# Как заполнить нулевую матрицу натуральными числами от 0

Tags: python, list, матрицы

Я заполнила матрицу нулями по заданным n и m. Далее создала цикл с вложенным циклом, где счетчик прибавляет единицу каждому элементу в строке. Но почему-то при выводе матрицы он сохранил во всех строках одинаковые элементы. В чем у меня ошибка?

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
a = []
tmp = [0] * m
for i in range(n):
    a.append(tmp)
for i in a:
    print(i)
    
с = 0    
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):        
        a[i][j] = с
        с += 1
        
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end = ' ')
    print()
```

Возвращает такое:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в принципе генерации матрицы:

Замените вот это:

```
a = []
tmp = [0] * m
for i in range(n):
    a.append(tmp)
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

на вот это:

```
a = [ [0 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

в вашем коде матрица a состоит из **`n`** строк `tmp`:

```
for i in range(n):
    a.append(tmp)
```

и когда вы изменяете по координатам `a[i][j] = с` матрицу, фактически вы изменяете список `tmp`, поэтому вы изменяете все строки матрицы, каждая из которых является `tmp`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, добрый человек!